# No SCM option on hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I install hudson also git plugin for hudson. But in project configuration there are no SCM option.

What can be the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install an additional plugin for the source code management system you are using. Ex: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Plugin